# The install alongside feature trying to install on the wrong drive (Ubuntu 20.04.1)

Tags: dual-boot

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 along side an existing Windows 10 installation that I have on a 256gb NVMe SSD.

However when I select to install the system alongside the Windows Boot Manager, the install instead chooses a 2TB HDD that is used for game storage only and has no boot partitions on it. The installer also attempted to use a USB HDD I had connected for backing the SSD up before allowing the installer to make changes.

Is the a way to change the drive that the install alongside feature tries to install to? The drop down menu in the installer window show no other available drives despite them all being detected and mountable by the system.

Comment: Did you shrink the windows partition (from windows) to make room for ubuntu on the ssd?